# How to post json from a search button?

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, post

I created a personal JSON file and when I consolo.log i can see is working but how can i post on the browser from a search button?
I cannot found a good explanation for this.
i have to display 4 small divs in a row with these 4 places below.
The user can only search the word "places" and i have to print places.name, places.imgage_urls, places.location_name, places.day_price, places.review_count

Here my code:

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Find a place to work..">
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="subtim" value="Search">
</form>

`<div id="results"></div>`
```

jQuery

```
$.getJSON("../test.json", function(data) {
console.log(data);
});

$.ajax({
    url: "../test.json",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $(data.places).each(function(index, value){
            console.log(value);
        });
    }
});
```

JSON

```
{
"places": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "HNK Flexplek",
        "imgage_urls": "https://d2h37djvgj7smg.cloudfront.net/0b4a33ef924631441bc371646c6c3830592c746d/18995.600x400x16919.jpg",
        "location_name": "HNK Amsterdam Houthavens",
        "day_price": 175,
        "review_count": 11
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Harrods",
        "imgage_urls": "https://d2h37djvgj7smg.cloudfront.net/4efa8f4624286e1890bdcfc82e9dfb06ccfb77ad/9492.600x400x16919.jpg",
        "location_name": "Het Warenhuis",
        "day_price": 200,
        "review_count": 4
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "V2",
        "imgage_urls": "https://d2h37djvgj7smg.cloudfront.net/cd6dfff88114b71ada941ff4e004b0cf143fdb3e/18996.600x400x16919.jpg",
        "location_name": "HNK Amsterdam Houthavens",
        "day_price": 260,
        "review_count": 13
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name": "LaFayette",
        "imgage_urls": "https://d2h37djvgj7smg.cloudfront.net/6f5a44425fd3892f70755fed536885e0476fc6b8/2328.600x400x16919.jpg",
        "location_name": "Het Warenhuis",
        "day_price": 150,
        "review_count": 0
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Do you mean user input a place and make ajax request to your test.json and get details of related places displayed?

Comment: i created the json file, so from the search button i would like to display all the contents properly, in my case the user can only search places

Comment: copy and test code https://jsfiddle.net/vncxfx0s/22/

Comment: my friend !!!! Thanks a lot !!! It worked.....actually is working but how can i display the result just if i search "places" in the imput box because like this they always been displayed

Comment: Glad to help you, an answer posted if there any issues comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#find_place").submit(liveSearch);
$("[name=search]").on("keyup",liveSearch);
function liveSearch(){
var inp = $("[name=search]").val().toLoweCase();

$.ajax({
    url: "../test.json",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "get",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $.each(data.places, function(i, v){
if(v.name.toLoweCase().indexOf(inp)>-1 || v.name.toLoweCase() == inp){
        $("results").append("<div id='place"+v.id+"' class='place'>"+
+"<h3>"+v.name+"</h3>"
+"<h5>"+v.location_name+"</h5>"
+"<img alt='"+v.location_name+"' title='"+v.location_name+"' src='"+v.imgage_urls+"'></img>"
+"<span>Day Price: "+v.day_price+"</span>"
+"<span>Review count: "+v.review_count+"</span>"
+"</div>");
}
        });
    }
})
return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='find_place'>
<input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Find a place to work..">
<input id="submit" type="submit" name="subtim" value="Search">
</form>

<div id="results"></div>
```

Comment: sorry still an issue, i would like them displayed JUST if i search places

Comment: sorry specify more

Comment: wherever i search they all will come out !!! i would like to see my json files just if i search the word places please

Comment: Yes you mean one place or related places not all places. that wat i point above, so Ok.

Comment: mmmm not really....i always want them to be displayed just if i write places in the search box otherwise some alert message that what i'm looking for doesn't exist

Comment: what issues you see?

Comment: you want live search on keypress

Comment: NaN means that there is invalid number do you try to make any calculations of price or whatever?

Answer (score 0):

Make an element in your HTML and give it an id. Then when your Ajax returns the contents of your json file, change the innerhtml of the element with the id.

Comment: Thanks, but Can i have a practical example please?

Answer (score 0):

In order to include the JSON value in your form, you'd need to store it in a form element.  Additionally, since all of that JSON would be a single value in the form, it would need to be serialized into a single string.

Add a form element within the form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="someName" id="someId" />
```

Then set its value:

```
$.getJSON("../test.json", function(data) {
    $('#someId').val(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```